# Executing python script from C# code mysteriously halts

Tags: c#, python, json

I currently have a set up in which I am using C# to execute a Python script. It also gets whatever the script would normally output in a command line returned back to be used in my application. (Except for error messages for some reason) The problem is that the script execution mysteriously comes to a halt when it reaches a line to open a .json file. I won't paste the script as it is fairly large, but I pinpointed the line it stops at by adding logs. This is the line:

```
featuresBody = open("features.json")
```

I have verified that the Python script makes it passed this point when I execute it in a regular command line, but halts here when executed from C#. Here is my C# code that runs the script:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
start.Arguments = ltrDirectory + "/train_and_upload_demo_model.py -c " + ltrDirectory + "/config.json";
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

This logic is picking up the script and running it in the beginning just fine, but just fails at that one line I noted above. I cannot get details as to what is wrong as error messages don't get returned to C# for whatever reason and I cannot replicate the issue in a command line because the same command works there.

Any ideas why opening a .json file works fine normally, but not when executed from C#...?